# How do I have a single multi-branch job that gets triggered for any branch that is create or updated?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins multi-branch pipelines as code- not freestyle jobs. I am not going to switch to free-style jobs because multi-branch pipelines have all the new features and DSL/scripted syntax and I rely on them heavily (ie Jenkinsfiles).

But I don't want to have a multi-branch job => branch mapping.

I also don't want to just track a single branch per se, I just want a single job that triggers off of *any* branch update. So this is not a matter of just filtering out which jobs I want to track from the repo.

I want to trigger the same job for every branch update and have that one job get passed the name of the branch that was updated.

I can configure the job to only track master which is fine for limiting it to only a single job, but I want that "master" branch job to be triggered for *any* branch update and be able to retrieve the branch that was updated from inside the master branch job run- so in the pipeline I know which branch triggered it.

Is this possible?